# Share network with second ethernet port ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, netplan

I want to share network from enp1s9 with second interface enp1s10.
The same function in windows bridge adapter.
I was trying use bridge and bonds, but without succes.
Becouse of ubuntu 17.10 I am using netplan.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
 version: 2
 ethernets:
  enp1s9:
   dhcp4: no
   dhcp6: no
   addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]
   gateway4: 192.168.0.1
   wakeonlan: true
   nameservers:
     addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
  enp1s10:
   dhcp4: true
   dhcp6: true
```

How I have to modify netplan??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have no `bridges` stanzas which suggests that you have not bothered reading the manual. `man 5 netplan` http://people.canonical.com/~mtrudel/netplan/

Comment: Hi @Ondrej, welcome to askubuntu -- if one of the answers works for you, please accept it (even your own is fine)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a bridge. As Ken Sharp posted, this is in [the documentation](http://people.canonical.com/~mtrudel/netplan/).

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
     enp1s9:
        dhcp4: false
     enp1s10:
        dhcp4: false
bridges:
    br0:
        interfaces: [ethernets]
        dhcp4: true
        parameters:
            stp: false
            forward-delay: 0
```

This should in theory work. I've not tested it, as I don't have a box with netplan avaialable.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have enp1s9 stil available on defined IP.

Comment: Why won't a IP on the bridge do?

Comment: I need to acces for other services running on server. Will be it possible when I set IP on bridge?

Comment: It will be possible. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
 version: 2
 ethernets:
     enp1s9:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      wakeonlan: true
      nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
     enp1s10:
        dhcp4: true
 bridges:
      br0:
        interfaces: [enp1s9, enp1s10]
        dhcp4: true
        parameters:
            stp: false
            forward-delay: 0
```